# Safari on Mac not offering to save passwords

Tags: macos, safari, password, keychain

I've been using a regular password manager, and when Safari would ask if I wanted to save passwords, I probably hit "Never" on many different sites. I'd like to start using the Keychain and let Safari do its thing, but the option doesn't come up anymore. I can add the passwords manually in the password preferences, but not automatically.

I've read that there was an option on the password page to turn off the "never save" option on sites, but that doesn't seem to be there any longer. And I don't see it in the website settings or anywhere else.

Is there some flag somewhere that I can turn off the "never save" feature?

On macOS 11.4, Safari 14.1.1